# What does Miracle Max mumble after Inigo says "Humiliations galore"?

Tags: dialogue, the-princess-bride

In *The Princess Bride*, in the scene where Inigo and Fezzik hire Miracle Max to restore Westley to life, the following dialogue occurs:

Miracle Max:

> I make him better, Humperdinck suffers?

Inigo:

> Humiliations galore.

Miracle Max:

> Ha ha ha! [Mumbles something.] That is a noble cause! Give me the sixty-five! I'm on the job!

([YouTube link](https://youtu.be/d4ftmOI5NnI?t=162s))

**What does Miracle Max mumble?**

Some dubious transcripts online state that he says "I'm gonna lick the Dalmatian," but I doubt that is accurate.

Comment: Would be great if you had a youtube of the scene

Comment: The Blu-ray subtitles say "(scatting)", which means saying nonsense words ([Scat singing - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scat_singing)).  It might actually be something in Yiddish though.

Comment: @morbo added YouTube link.

Comment: I always thought it was Yiddish

Comment: I always heard, “Hide a little Danish.”

Comment: The last couple syllables always sounded like some kind of elongated, sing-song version of "humiliation." Like he's somehow re-stating the goal to himself in his zeal. I think there are either 6 or 7 syllables in total (from my memory).

Comment: "Hudemickiniliation" https://everywordmeans.livejournal.com/318133.html - that's what it sounds like by the end but I'm pretty sure it stars with *I’m gonna lick the* (day may shine).... And before it gets deleted : *I think* "He sings “I’m gonna lick the Le Méchant!” - Le Méchant is French which can be translated; bad, jerk, naughty child, wicked, villain, etc." (in French the T at the end is silent)

Comment: Funny that it seems to be dubbed in as an afterthought. His back is turned for most of it, and if I'm not mistaken, his mouth isn't moving for the little bit we can see. So perhaps a joke they thought of after shooting it and felt it was funny enough to put in... if only it were intelligible...

Answer (score 7):

**It's unclear but it seems that this may just have been Billy Crystal ad-libbing a few words.**

Certainly the original book by William Goldman has nothing and the same is true in his screenplay adaptation.

> “Humiliations galore,” Inigo said.
>
> “Now that’s what I call a worth-while reason,” Miracle Max said. “Give me the sixty-five; I’m on the case.”
>
> <sup>*The Princess Bride* - Novel by William Goldman</sup>

---

> ```
>                     INIGO
>         Humiliations galore!
>
>                     MIRACLE MAX
>         That is a noble cause. Give me
>        the sixty-five, I'm on the job.
> ```
>
> <sup>*The Princess Bride* - [Screenplay](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/princess_bride.html) by William Goldman</sup>

The Blu-Ray subtitles would also seem to indicate that this is just nonsense ad-libbing as they just read "SCATTING" which is described by [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scat_singing) as...

> In vocal jazz, scat singing is vocal improvisation with wordless vocables, nonsense syllables or without words at all. In scat singing, the singer improvises melodies and rhythms using the voice as an instrument rather than a speaking medium.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

He sings “I’m gonna lick the Le Méchant!”

Le Méchant is French wich can be translated;
bad,
jerk,
naughty child,
wicked,
villain, etc.

Miracle Max is exclaiming that he is going to lick (get/punish) the evil villain, Humperdinck by helping Wesley, Inigo, and Fezzik.
The actor of Miracle Max was not simply improvising gibberish.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence that this is what he's supposed to have said?